# Do triangles with sides satisfying $b+c=2a$ or $b+c=3a$ have special names? Are there references for them?

Tags: geometry, reference-request, terminology, triangles

References about two classes of special triangles needed.

Specifically, the triangles having the property $b+c=2a$ and respectively $b+c=3a$, where $a,b,c$ are the standard notations for the lengths of the sides.

Have these triangles special names? Can you please name same references about them, if there is such thing?

Comment: Any equilateral triangle trivially satisfies $b+c=2a$, since $b=c=a$.

Comment: I don't know if they have special names, but they are all the triangles formed by the two foci of an appropriate ellipse (different in each case) and any point on the circumference of the ellipse.